# Storing files from Imgur in POSTGRES using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to set up a database to store png files extracted from Imgur and I wanted to know if it would be possible to directly store my images into my database rather than just the link. I currently am storing image links from a txt file with selected Imgur links using activerecord in my seed.rb file as seen in the code below:

```
image = []
images_c = [:url]

x = 0

while x < 25 do
    image_hash = {:url => url_file_lines[x]}
    image << image_hash
    x = x + 1
end

Image.import images_c, import, validate: false
```

I currently have a good idea of how to retrieve the files via the imgur link but am having a hard time figuring out how to convert the image file into a datatype that could be stored into the postgres db.

Comment: While you can store files in `bytea` or `lob` columns [there are plenty of good reasons why you should not store the files in the database](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database).

Answer (score 0):

Store images in database (blob) is a bad idea. Just because you will get unnecessary growth of db. Instead of store in database - I recommend use some gems for storing files ([shrine](https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine)). If you has not any cloud storage - you can just save it in on your local storage. You just need add column `image_data` at your table with type `jsonb` (as you use postgres) and then mount uploader class into your model (like on gem documentation).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Really appreciate the help.